# How to prevent HTML objects from moving "down" when a table is populated dymamically

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, dynamic

I am populating a table at the very top of my HTML page dynamically.  However, whenever this table is populated the HTML objects and data located "below" this table are moved down on the page as rows are populated into the table.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: So you want the table to display *on top* of the rest of the page? Like a layer?

Comment: I would want the table to have a static position and populate itself without it having any effect on any of the other HTML elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either remove the bottom rows of the table or give the table an absolute position. i'm not sure why you would want that thought.

Comment: absolute position it's the answer.

Comment: removing the bottom rows of the table would be counter-intuitive seeing as how I want them to dynamically be populated, however the positioning may be the answer I am looking for

Comment: The positioning was it! Thank you